# jQuery: dynamically selecting elements by class with .find()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am working on a form with many sections. Within each section there is a radio button used to indicate which units the user would like to use (lbs/oz vs kg, etc). When they click on a unit, I'd like to hide() all the inputs in the same section, then show() the relevant ones.

I can't get it to work. I think I am misunderstanding the find() function somehow because it is not selecting any elements.

```
var show_hide_units = function (selectedUnitElement) {
    $element = $(selectedUnitElement);
    unit_class = $element.attr("class");
    $section = $($element.parents('.measurement'));
    $inputs = $($section.find('.inputs *'));
    $inputs.hide();
    $inputs.find('.' + unit_class).show();
};
```

Here is a fiddle showing more context: http://jsfiddle.net/32Q9t/

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: perhaps you wanted to use `filter` instead of `find`? `find` searches among the children.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Thank you, but no - the elements I want to show are descendants of the $inputs element

Comment: then you're trying to show a descendant of a hidden node. Children of hidden nodes are hidden as well, no matter what.

Comment: @JanDvorak: you are totally right about the descendant of a hidden child. Thanks, sometimes you stare so long you cant see the obvious. I hid less and switched to filter and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you choose to hide all `'.inputs *'` elements (which isn't the simplest solution at all), then you must show much more inputs that what you do, as elements "visible" in hidden aren't really visible :

```
$inputs.parent().find('.' + unit_class+', .' + unit_class+' *').show();
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/C8Mzy/)

A simpler solution would be to hide/show only one level of elements :

```
$('.inputs > *').hide();
$('.inputs > .'+unit_class).show();
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/jRsHK/)

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/find/ :

> .find( selector )
>   Description: Get the descendants of each element in
>   the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery
>   object, or element.

So just use `$('.youClass')` to match target elements.

```
var show_hide_units = function (selectedUnitElement) {
    var targetClass = $(selectedUnitElement).attr('class');
    $('.inputs > *').hide();
    $('.' + targetClass).show();
};
```

There you go with your forked fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BE8ZV/

Comment: +1 because I see now that you proposed basically what I propose, before me.

Comment: unfortunately that class is used in too many other areas to do it that way, but the real issue was i was showing nodes with hidden parents

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to use the JavaScript debugger? That's the real answer to your question. Here's how to get started: In your fiddle, insert a `debugger;` statement at the beginning of your `show_hide_units()` function, like in this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geary/32Q9t/3/). I also made a few minor changes to your code, adding missing `var` declarations, and removing the redundant `$()` wrappers on two lines. (The return value from `.parents()` or `.find()` is a jQuery object already.)

What I didn't do is fix the bug. Now here is how to start: load that page in Chrome and open the Developer Tools. Then click one of your radio buttons and it will stop on that `debugger;` statement. From there you can examine variables by hovering over them, single-step through the code, and do all sorts of useful things. Poke around in there for a while and you should find the bug, or if not, report back with what you've discovered in the debugger and we can kick it around some more.

Comment: thanks for the tip! I knew about the tool but didn't know about inserting the line in the function.